# Windows Desktop icons move to other monitor every reboot

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, desktop-icons

Every time I reboot my computer the desktop icons get moved to my other monitor... they are still in the same relative position, just the wrong screen.  My taskbar is on the correct screen, which makes me think it might be nvidia's drivers.

Comment: Is your secondary monitor set up on the primary connector and you've moved the taskbar manually?

Comment: No, the monitor with the taskbar is the primary and I did not move the taskbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try To use UltraMon and StarDock Fences.

Fences is grouping Icons and can be always on same place.

Answer (score 1):

This annoying bug is still present in Windows 10. After moving my icons back to the primary monitor numerous times, I hit on an idea. It worked!

With your icons positioned where you want them, right-click the desktop in the secondary monitor and create a new shortcut. Doesn't matter what it's a shortcut to—you'll never use it. 
I pointed mine to a non-existent URL and called it "Monitor holder":

[image]

That's it! Ever since I added this dummy shortcut, my icons have stayed on the correct monitor after every restart.